# Trying to use Google Maps v1, extending Overlay, to animate a series of bitmaps

Tags: android, google-maps

I already have code to display a bitmap image, extending Overlay,
and using Google Maps API v1, similar to other code to try to
do a GroundOverlay, and it works, but now I want to
"animate" a series of bitmaps, instead of a single one.

All the code out there is for Markers, or single images,
or creating a path, or creating multiple images, but nothing for "animating"
a series of bitmaps.

I'd like to stay with v1.  I'm mostly interested in how the onCreate()
and the class extending Overlay would work, I've already worked out
how to download the images using a background Thread.

I imagine that a lot of the code would be similar to doing a single image,
but I don't know..

Right now I'm using draw(Canvas, MapView, shadow), and setting shadow to 'false',
I'm not quite sure how to use the version that uses 'long when'.

If anyone could provide a link to a code example that would do this,
or something close to it, that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: In my test code I'm setting up the MapView and calling setZoom() and setCenter() later I have a loop that downloads the image in the background and fills in an Overlay and the screen is black until it finally drops out of the loop, THEN it finally calls draw() and puts up the Google Map background and the final image shows.  In the loop I call getOverlays() do a clear() and add() the Overlay then do an invalidate(), but it never calls draw(), what can I do to "force" it  do a draw()?  I checked and the Bitmap object is valid each time.